# Render 16 bits image in picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox, pixel

I have an array which consists in PixelData extracted from a Dicom Image.

Here's the code:

```
        byte[] bytes = img.PixelData.GetFrame(0).Data; // img is the Dicom Image
        int count = bytes.Length / 2;
        ushort[] words = new ushort[count];
        for (int i = 0, p = 0; i < count; i++, p += 2)
        {
            words[i] = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, p);
        }
        pixels16 = words.ToList(); //pixels16 contains now the PixelData for the Grayscale image
```

Now, here's my question, how do I render that into a Picturebox??

Answer (score 1):

My code for converting Bitmaps from Format16bppGrayScale to Format8bppIndexed format. PictureBox can easy show this format. (If you want, you can use different palette).

```
public Bitmap Gray16To8bppIndexed(Bitmap BmpIn)
{
    if (BmpIn.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale)
        throw new BadImageFormatException();

    byte[] ImageData = new byte[BmpIn.Width * BmpIn.Height * 2];
    Rectangle Re = new Rectangle(0, 0, BmpIn.Width, BmpIn.Height);

    BitmapData BmpData = BmpIn.LockBits(Re, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, BmpIn.PixelFormat);
    Marshal.Copy(BmpData.Scan0, ImageData, 0, ImageData.Length);
    BmpIn.UnlockBits(BmpData);

    byte[] ImageData2 = new byte[BmpIn.Width * BmpIn.Height];
    for (long i = 0; i < ImageData2.LongLength; i++)
        ImageData2[i] = ImageData[i * 2 + 1];
    ImageData = null;

    Bitmap BmpOut = new Bitmap(BmpIn.Width, BmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    BmpData = BmpOut.LockBits(Re, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, BmpOut.PixelFormat);
    Marshal.Copy(ImageData2, 0, BmpData.Scan0, ImageData2.Length);
    BmpOut.UnlockBits(BmpData);
    ImageData2 = null;
    BmpData = null;

    ColorPalette GrayPalette = BmpOut.Palette;
    Color[] GrayColors = GrayPalette.Entries;
    for (int i = 0; i < GrayColors.Length; i++)
        GrayColors[GrayColors.Length - 1 - i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
    BmpOut.Palette = GrayPalette;

    return BmpOut;
}
```

Comment: I had to change the line "ImageData2[i] = ImageData[i * 2 + 1];" by removing the "+ 1", so I guess in my case the endianness was the other way round for some reason. But now your solution works great!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know the specifics, because it depends on how you really want to go about it (if performance is important, you need to create your own subclass of Bitmap, but otherwise, Bitmap.SetPixel would work fine).

But essentially, you need to shove those pixels into a Bitmap, then set the picture box's image to that bitmap, like:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);

for(int y = 0;y < height;y++)
   for(int x = 0;x < width;x++)
       bitmap.SetPixel(x,y, Color.fromRGB(/* unpack your R,G,B channel of your pixel here */);

pictureBox.Image = bitmap;
```

Comment: I will give it a try.
I also tried this:
`MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);`
`Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);`
but I get an error

Comment: That will only work if 'bytes' contains the same sort of packed image data you would find in a JPG or a PNG.  It will automatically figure out which type of image you passed it and read it as if it was a file.  However, your `img` is an already loaded, unpacked image, so I doubt the `Image.FromStream` approach will work for you.

Comment: So If I shove the pixels into a bitmap, will I loose the 16bpp format since bmp is usually 24bpp or 32bpp?
The whole idea behind this is to get the correct pixelvalue later on when the user clicks a point in the picturebox. I will be basically giving the 24bpp value rather than the 16bpp value if I use a bmp am I right?

Comment: Well, Bitmap actually has many different ways of storing the image data.  You can specify the format for the pixels when you create the bitmap, so you could choose to keep it 16bpp if you want.  I think there's one constructor method of Bitmap that takes width, height, and PixelFormat.  Actually, from boli below:

`System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);`

Comment: But besides that, you could just as well just display a 24bpp image, and then, when the user clicks on a pixel, you could sample out of your original image to grab the exact color.  Depends on what you're doing, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks, How can I sample out from the original image since the one being shown is 24bppp? is there an easy way or code to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the AForge .NET Framework, which is a great .NET library for image processing. The built-in .NET Picturebox could not nativley display images with System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, but the AForge library has its own [Picturebox](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/8c467fcd-2a62-4d8a-2a5c-3696df44d8de.htm) control, check this out. It [expects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7e7b2kd) a .NET Image.

You can include AForge to your project easily with NuGet:

```
Install-Package AForge.Controls
Install-Package AForge.Imaging
```

Or just

`Install-Package AForge`

Example code below:

```
//SOME BYTES
//Load here the DICOM image
int width=640, height=480;
int numberOfPixels = width*height;
byte[] source = new byte[2*numberOfPixels];

//With AFORGE
var image = AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage.Create(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
IntPtr ptrToImage = image.ImageData;
//Copies the bytes from source to the image
//System.Runtime.InteropServices
Marshal.Copy(source, 0, ptrToImage,numberOfPixels);

//WITH .NET
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
var imageData = bitmapImage.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
Marshal.Copy(source, 0, imageData.Scan0, numberOfPixels);
bitmapImage.UnlockBits(imageData);
```

Comment: Thanks, so that code you put above with .NET actually works for 16bpp images?

Comment: I have used Marshal.Copy before, but not on 16 bpp images. I think it should work, but do not forget to use the Picturebox from AForge. Scaling the 16 bit pixel values to 8 bit pixel value could work either.

Comment: I tried the .net code and didn't work (I see a red cross in the place of the picturebox)
What I did was: `picbox_mpr.Image = imageData;` right after the last line

Comment: Ok, I tried Aforge and works, but how you assign the image to the aforge picturebox?

Comment: picbox_mpr.Image = imageData; won't work. The imageData variable holds information about the managed Bitmap (location in the memeory, ...). When you call the LockBits, the Bitmap will be pinned in the memory, that's why you can play with it easily, without any risk. You should try picbox_mpr.Image = bitmapImage; I also think that instead of Marshal.Copy(source, 0, imageData.Scan0, numberOfPixels); try Marshal.Copy(source, 0, imageData.Scan0, 2*numberOfPixels);, because the source (which is byte[]) has also 2*numberOfPixels elements. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146625.aspx

Comment: If you use AForge, UnmanagedImage should be converted to managed image. http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/71166cdd-d6d1-6385-d17e-cd25fc5b6d36.htm

Answer (score 0):

Got this idea from a friend. The *inputImage.ImageSource* property is a 2D array with grayscale pixel values.

```
Bitmap grayscaleImage = new Bitmap(inputImage.ImageSource);
            for (int x = 0; x < grayscaleImage.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < grayscaleImage.Height; y++)
                {
                    byte[,] tempMatrix = inputImage.ImageGrayscale;
                    byte temp = tempMatrix[x, y];
                    Color tempColor = Color.FromArgb(255, temp, temp, temp);
                    grayscaleImage.SetPixel(x, y, tempColor);
                }
            }
            picboxDisplay.Image = grayscaleImage;
```