# c# convert 16-bit image (grayscale) to Bitmap (RGB888) object format

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, bitmap, openni

I am using OpenNI 2 as PrimeSense API and trying to capture IR stream (which is in 16 bit grayscale format), and finally want it to display in PictureBox on the WinForm. (I am using c# .NET)

I am stuck on how to convert 16 bit image format to Bitmap object in C#.

`VideoFrameRef ir_frame = ir.readFrame();`   ---->> This gives 16 bit image in `VideoFrameRef` type

& want to convert `ir_frame` to .net's Bitmap object to show in PictureBox.

1. How this conversion can be done ?
2. How OpenCV/ equivalent library can be used here ?

Please advice.
Thanks !

Comment: Shift each 16-bit pixel right by 8 bits, then put the result in each of the 8-bit R, G & B channels of a 24-bit Bitmap (or a 32-bit Bitmap with Alpha always set to 255).

Comment: Try my code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42123760/5849511

Comment: have look it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426431/how-to-downgrade-16-bit-depth-gray-scale-to-8-bit-depth-image-rgb-24